# Element not found in UI Test Case using XCTestCase Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3, xctestcase

I am trying to create UI test Cases using Xcode 7 and I am facing an issue that Ui elements such as buttons, tables are detected randomly when I run the test cases and most of the times it gives an error saying that "Failed to find the element". It is not resolved even after adding delays to the same. Can anyone please help.

The code for the same is 
XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().orientation = .Portrait

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    app.buttons["Login"].tap()

    let app2 = app
    self.waitForHittable(app.tables.cells.staticTexts["Login with Email"], waitSeconds: 30)

    app2.tables.cells.staticTexts["Login with Email"].tap()
    app.textFields["Email address"].tap()
    app.textFields["Email address"].typeText("anil@gmail.com")

    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "anil1234"
    app.secureTextFields["Password"].doubleTap()
    app.menuItems["Paste"].tap()

    app.buttons["Login with Email"].tap()
    self.waitForHittable(app.navigationBars["HomeView"].buttons["ic menu"], waitSeconds: 60)
    app.navigationBars["HomeView"].buttons["ic menu"].tap()
```

If I write the code     app.buttons["Login"].tap()
 twice, it works or else it wont be able to find the subsequest control elements.

Comment: Please can you post example code and the output of XCUIApplication.debugDescription?

Comment: Post a code example

Comment: I have edited the question with the code I have use. Please suggest.